# JavaScript replace src attribute if path has value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some markup that includes images with the following `src` attribute:

```
https://url.com/image/img.jpg
```

I want to replace any image (or `href`) that contains `/image/` in its path. So the result would be:

```
https://newurl.com/img.jpg
```

I've tried using:

```
/src="(?:[^'\/]*\/)*([^']+)"/g
```

but not sure how to get it to only match `/image/` paths, also when I change `src` to `href` it doesn't seem to allow me to replace both.

To clarify, I'm parsing plain text that happens to contain html strings.  Also, I need to be able to maintain the file name, but replace the host address.

Update: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq9y6raL/1/) of what I have so far.  Although it works for the `src`, it's not taking into account the `/image/` in the path, also it removes the href.

Comment: why don't you create a Regex for `/image/` only ?

Comment: Don't be complicated unless you find you need to be - `src.replace('/image/','/')`

Comment: Btw can u please post the whole statement instead of regex only? Proggys can be silly at times lol. I do it everyday heh :D

Comment: I added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

[**Obligatory don't use regex to parse HTML...**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

---

Since you are already using JavaScript, you could use the native DOM API to iterate over all of the `img` elements and update the `src` attributes:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), function(img) {
  img.src = img.src.replace(/\/image\//, '/');
});
```

---

But since you clarified that you have a string that contains HTML, you could create a temporary element, insert the string as HTML, replace the `src` attributes, and then retrieve the updated `innerHTML` property value.

For example:

```js
var content = `string of content containing random text, some elements, <p>and paragraphs</p> and more text.. <img src="https://url.com/image/img.jpg" /><img src="https://url.com/image/img.jpg" />`;

// Create the temporary DOM element
var temporaryElement = document.createElement('div');
temporaryElement.innerHTML = content;

// Replace the `src` attributes
Array.from(temporaryElement.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach((img) => {
  img.src = img.src.replace(/\/image\//, '/');
});

// Retrieve the updated `innerHTML` property
var updatedContent = temporaryElement.innerHTML;
console.log(updatedContent);
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I'm not parsing dom, this is just plain text content that happens to have html elements.

Comment: This one fails if the URL happens to end in `image` like `https://newurl.com/somepath/image.jpg` - check for the presence of the trailing slash. Then again, the OP didn't explicitly say that wasn't the desired behaviour....nevermind.

Comment: @dzm - Like this? I just updated the fiddle you posted.. https://jsfiddle.net/3mgo3u8L/

Comment: @JoshCrozier  Thanks, it looks like this could work, although I'd really prefer to use regex.  I'm doing this server side and while I could put it into dom, it'd be much cleaner/faster I think to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

**This Should Work.**

**REGEXP:**

```
(?:^(?:https:\/{2})(?:\w*\.*|\d*\.*)(?:\w*|\d*)*(?:\/image\/))(.+)$
```

**INPUT:**

```
https://url.com/image/img.jpg
https://url.com/image/asdasdasd.jpg
```

**REPLACE with:** https://newurl.com/

```
https://newurl.com/$1
```

**RESULT:**

```
https://newurl.com/img.jpg
https://newurl.com/asdasdasd.jpg
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```js
const regex = /(?:^(?:https:\/{2})(?:\w*\.*|\d*\.*)(?:\w*|\d*)*(?:\/image\/))(.+)$/gm;
const str = `https://url.com/image/img.jpg
https://url.com/image/asdasdasd.jpg
`;
const subst = `https://newurl.com/\$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

**See:** https://regex101.com/r/I4hHV7/2

Comment: This is close, but if there's any other text in `str`, it doesn't seem to replace.